# Contact Form 7 stuck on sending mail

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-16.04, contact-form-7, linode

I recently bought a machine from linode and configured it with ubuntu 16 and a lemp server. I installed my wordpress site, everything it's working fine exept for Contact Form 7. The form is configured correctly because I copied it from another site which is hosted on a shared hosting platform. Before installing sendmail on ubuntu the form gave me an error, now it's stuck on sending. Does anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: look at then XHR logs sending, and error logs from your server. Then give us details

Comment: I ran "sendmailconfig", contact form 7 tells me the mail was sent, but in reality the mail still doesn't arrive. In the browser the request is fine (status code 200)

Comment: Then if error doens't comes from php side, go get a loook around SMTP or things like that

Comment: Yes, it's SMTP  settings error.